# Hyperlink at a specific area

Tags: css, html

I am making a website for Family Guy, I have their picture as the background of the homepage. Now, I want when I click anywhere on Stewie(on the background) to activate a hyperlink and go to Stewie's webpage and same thing goes for the others, what language could I use for that?
CSS, HTML5, JQuery?

Or if the background could be like black and the family members could be pictures but still, I want to activate the hyperlink when I go over the family member and not the empty space around their heads etc.

Comment: Use the [HTML `<map>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an image map.  Here is an example from W3 Schools:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

There are also some tools out there to assist with mapping the areas.  They should be easy to Google.